# Qt print-to-pdf-feature missing with deployed app and installed printer dll

Tags: windows, qt, dll

As I deployed an application that needs printing support, I figured that I only could print to pdf. I found out that I needed the plugin `windowsprintersupport.dll` in the folder "printsupport". So then, I could find printers and print, but the option to print to pdf was gone... If I remove the plugin and restart the app, it does not find any printers yet again, but can print to pdf. Of course I still want to be able to print to pdf, how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried dependency walker?

Comment: No I haven't yet. I will install PdfCreator on the machine to see if it installs a pdf-printer. Perhaps then it will work